# append select option value and text using json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have receive json object form server like below one,

```
{"locations": [{"locationCode": "Branch 1","locationName": "BR-001"},

               {"locationCode": "Branch 2","locationName": "BR-002"},

               {"locationCode": "Branch 3","locationName": "BR-003"}
              ]}
```

then I need to append  **locationCode** for **value** and **locationName** for the **text**

```
<option value="locationCode">locationName</option>
```

I have tried this one but couldn't do it

```
    var location = data.locations;
        $.each(location, function (key, value) {
        $('#newLocation')
          .append($("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", key)
          .text(value));
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over array i.e. **`locations`** not on map 
so change your code to

```
var location = data.locations;
        $.each(location, function (index) {
        $('#newLocation')
          .append($("<option></option>")
          .attr("value", location[index].locationCode)
          .text(location[index].locationName));
        });
```

**Update:-**

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/ymsq1uoy/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
var locations = 
  [
    {"locationCode": "Branch 1","locationName": "BR-001"},

    {"locationCode": "Branch 2","locationName": "BR-002"},

    {"locationCode": "Branch 3","locationName": "BR-003"}
  ];


for (var i=0;i<locations.length;i++){
    var value = locations[i].locationCode;
    var text  = locations[i].locationName;
    var opt = "<option value='"+value+"' >"+text+"</option>";
    $('#newLocation').append(opt);
}
```

OR :

```
var loc = new Object();
var loc = {"locations": 
  [
    {"locationCode": "Branch 1","locationName": "BR-001"},

    {"locationCode": "Branch 2","locationName": "BR-002"},

    {"locationCode": "Branch 3","locationName": "BR-003"}
  ]
};
for (var i=0;i<loc.locations.length;i++){
    var value = loc.locations[i].locationCode;
    var text  = loc.locations[i].locationName;
    var opt = "<option value='"+value+"' >"+text+"</option>";
    $('#newLocation').append(opt);
}
```

Comment: _Try this_ solutions are low-value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.  Please improve your answer to include how your solution works and why it is a good idea.